# Aligning text in span which is inside p element

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to align some text which is enclosed in span which is itself inside a p element. But it is not working.

```
<p>This line has no alignment.<br /><span class="new">This is right aligned</span></p>
```

The CSS code is-

```
.new {text-align: right;}
```

What is wrong in my CSS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
p{
display: inline-block;
}
.new{
float:right;
}
```

What exactly are you trying to achieve?
Can you give a screenshot of what you want?